# Mount a file collection in a linux environment

Tags: command-line, files, mount, data-recovery, forensics

I am presently working as a summer intern.

My first objective is, given a collection of files, recover and identify the file types present in it.

To download sample pseudo-forensics data I have been using: [Digital Corpora](http://digitalcorpora.org/corpora/disk-images)  for pseudo corpus. I am trying to mount the disk images provided in this site, they are of type E01 ,E02 etc. I have tried using the ***mount*** command in linux. I have not been successful so far. Please provide methods to mount such pseudo corpus in a linux environment.

Answer (score 0):

The site has [a page that mentions the procedure](http://digitalcorpora.org/corpora/disk-images/format-conversion) to convert the Encase format files to RAW format (.dd). Once you're able to convert the files to .dd files, you can simply mount them using the `mount` utility:

`mount filename.dd /mnt/temp/`

Comment: when i try options given in that page the following happens : 1.it asks for me to install ewf-tools.

Comment: @MANU Ok, so you installed ewf-tools. And what did you do after that?